# Is there a way to get the position of the scrollIndicator in a collectionview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a CollectionView with horizontal scroll direction in a UIView. I want to hide the scroll indicator and draw a line in its place. I am trying to retrieve the y coordinate of the scroll indicator so I can use it to position the line on top of the scroll indicator. How can get the y coordinate of the scroll indicator in my view?

Comment: why do you need the y position if you hide it?

Comment: I need the y position to draw a line in the same spot as the scroll indicator

Answer (score 1):

a scrollview by default contains two subviews. the first is an imageview representing the horizontal scrollindicator and the second is an imageview representing the vertical scrollindicator. so:

```
let horizontalScrollIndicatorY = scrollView.subviews.first!.frame.origin.y
print(horizontalScrollIndicatorY)
```

Comment: How can I access "scrollview" in a collectionView? Also, could you please post your answer in objective c?

Comment: When I say self.scrollView, I get an error that says "Property 'scrollView' not found on object of type UICollectionView"